# UnicodeEncodeError when formatting string with % in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, formatting

For the life of me, I cannot figure this out: I am just trying to extract messages and who said them from a .json file. While I cannot disclose those data here, this is the line that does it:

```
print '<%s> %s' % (x['sender_id'], x['content'][0]['text'])
```

"x" is the dict containing the things I need to know. The output on each line is to look like so:

```
<username> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

as seen in many IRC logs. Anyway, both of the strings in the tuple there are Unicode. That is to say they are formally of the Python unicode type. I checked. However when I try to format them into that string, the result is always something like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f52b' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried many things, such as writing this instead:

```
print u'<%s> %s' % (x['sender_id'], x['content'][0]['text'])
```

Or:

```
print '<%s> %s' % (x['sender_id'], x['content'][0]['text']).encode('utf-8')
```

and I have tried combining those two strategies, and other things besides, but *nothing* I have tried works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably `print` writing to `stdout` with an ASCII encoding, which is causing the problem. Check the value of `sys.stdout.encoding` to be sure. Either make sure you only print ASCII strings or set the default stdout encoding to something more reasonable like UTF-8 with the `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable. Example:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python myprogram.py
```

Comment: The plot has thickened actually. I noticed that it was only this one character that was a problem, namely: . The others went through without complaints. Also your advice didn't work. Thank you anyway. I'm sort of beginning to believe that there might be either a bug in Python or a malformed or peculiar / proprietary Unicode character here. Apparently it's supposed to be an image of a pistol: http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/376/events/pistol-or-revolver

Comment: What is `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: By default, None. I just looked through bash history and realized that I had written PYTHONENCODING instead of PYTHONIOENCODING. It works now.